# Underscore _.object function not working

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Just i tried underscore _.object function but i am getting only undefined value.

Example my code:

```
var arr = [['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50]];
var str=JSON.stringify(array);
str.substring(1,str.length-1);
_.object(str.substring(1,str.length-1));
```

Result only Undefined

I cant find any mistake anyone help me...

Thanks...

Comment: `substring` does not mutate the original string. (primitives are immutable), in case you were trying to do something on line 3.

Comment: You're creating a variable called `arr`, but then referencing a variable called `array`. Also, please tell us what you expect this code to do. `_.object` expects an array, so why are you passing a string into it?

Comment: what you want as output?

Comment: [`JSON`](http://json.org) is text, not code. It is used to transport a data structure between two different programs that handle it. It doesn't help here (and decoding it to recover the data used to generate it is the only meaningful way to process a JSON).

Answer (score 1):

[`_.object`](http://underscorejs.org/#object) takes two arrays as parameters. First acts as the keys of the objects, and second acts as the values of the corresponding keys.

You need to call the method by [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)ing it over your array, like this:

```js
var arr = [
  ['moe', 'larry', 'curly'],
  [30, 40, 50]
];

console.log(_.object.apply(null, arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

or if your browser supports ES6 syntax, use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
var arr = [
  ['moe', 'larry', 'curly'],
  [30, 40, 50]
];

console.log(_.object(...arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you intend is `{moe: 30, larry: 40, curly: 50}`,
you'll need to do `_.object(arr[0], arr[1]);`

In the above case at `var str=JSON.stringify(array);`, str is equal to `"[["moe","larry","curly"],[30,40,50]]"`

P.S: `.substring` method returns a new string and does not change the original string.